# Switch SFP+, 16 100/1000Mb Ports, SNMP support, active cooling

Tags: switch

I am searching for a Switch with at least 1 SFP+ and 16 100/1000Mbit Ports, Jumbo Frames with at least 9216Bytes and SNMP support. 
I used a DGS 1510 Series Switch from D-Link until now, but the SNMP features are buggy. The size is important too (the smaller the better) and it should have active cooling.
Vlans should be supported too.

**Edit:**
Price can go up to 200€, There are two cases where these switches will be used.
One time under a machine and one time in a switching box.
Measurment should not exceed 280 × 180 × 44 mm.

**Edit2:**
The switches are not used for internet access, just for point to point connections, so port features are not necessary. An integrated web-server would be nice too.